# SLES checking file systems... stuck at boot after reboot

Tags: boot, raid, vmware, fsck, sles

[image]

After reboot the boot is stuck on a SLES machine.

Already tried a "touch /forcefsck" from a livecd to force fsck at boot, but it didn't help, still the same. Also fsck'ed rootlv from livecd.

**Q:** how can I continue the boot?

"21 LV active" looks like it successfully activated them.. but why does it get stuck?

**EDIT1:** Only can reach it remotely. Running on VMware. Connected through VMware console.

Tried to boot with an older kernel, didn't help, the same problem.

Tried to add the "debug  initcall_debug" to the boot options, didn't helped.

sw raid1 was _U before reboot, but this is "normal here" :)

Comment: only can reach it via remotely. running on vmware.

Comment: currently a vmware console

Comment: already tried to boot a livecd, issue an fsck -y /dev/rootvg/root_lv it said it is clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding:

```
fastboot
```

option to the boot options solved the problem, the system is up :)

update: later noticed: the last "done" wasn't for fsck.